# Data variable dont get the response in vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, axios, vuejs3

I do a get in the api and I can collect their data but when I assign it to a data variable it doesn't get it

```
data() {
    return {
      departamento: [],
    }
  },
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      const token = setToken.getToken();
      axios
        .get("https://sig-fpto.herokuapp.com/api/departamentos/buscarTodos", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.departamento = response.data
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err.response));
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing Vue2 syntax with Vue3. Here is what should work:

```
  setup() {
    const departamento = ref([]);

    onMounted(() => {
      const token = setToken.getToken();
      axios
        .get("https://sig-fpto.herokuapp.com/api/departamentos/buscarTodos", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          departamento.value = [...response.data];
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err.response));
    })

    return {
      departamento,
    }
  }
```

Comment: its vue3????????

Comment: You put `vuejs3` in your tags.
What I wrote is Vue3 with composition API.